# How to eliminate the values from array if it contains specific characters/string in JavaScript/lodash?

Tags: javascript, lodash

I am having one array with some values like below,

**let a = ["Mango","1243greatApple","goodOrange","Watermelon","ThisGoodalsoberemoved","GreatOrange","Pappaya","BestApple"];**

Now, I want to eliminate the values which contains string like Great and Good in the values.

Expecting output like below,

**["Mango","Watermelon","Pappaya","BestApple"]**

Tried using lodash, but it works only when it matches exact string. But i need it like regex match. Please help me out with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In vanilla JS, you can try with [**`Array.prototype.filter()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

> The `filter()` method creates a new array with all elements that pass the test implemented by the provided function.

And [**`String.prototype.includes()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes)

> The includes() method determines whether one string may be found within another string, returning `true` or `false` as appropriate.

```js
let a = ["Mango","1243GreatApple","GoodOrange","Watermelon","ThisGoodalsoberemoved","GreatOrange","Pappaya","BestApple"];

var r = a.filter(f => !(f.includes('Great') || f.includes('Good')));
console.log(r);
```

Comment: And if lodash is somehow a requirement for you, the [`lodash.filter`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#filter) should also be compatible with [`.includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes).  Do note, however, that IE does not support `.includes`.

Comment: @AlexanderNied can use `String.search` instead, [`search mdn`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search) or can use `test` also

Comment: This will not work when we filter smallcase good,great. any function with out case sensitive?

Comment: @DeepakKumar, yes, you can use `toLowerCase()` like  `a.filter(f => !(f.toLowerCase().includes('great') || f.toLowerCase().includes('good')))`